Laravel Many-to-Many Relationship giving wrong result
I am developing a database for giveaways. I have two main tables: participants and giveaways with an N:N relationship since a participant can participate to one or more giveaways and a giveaway can have one or more participants. My (simplified) table structure is the following:
giveaways 
----------------------
uuid    name


participant_giveaway
----------------------
id    giveaway_uuid    fiscal_code 


participants
----------------------
fiscal_code    first_name    last_name

Now, I have followed the docs for Laravel 11 but the relationship gives me wrong results. For instance, I have 4 participants for a giveaway and when I try to retrieve them with Giveaway::find($uuid)->participants, it returns 2 random participants that are linked to another giveaway.
This is my Giveaway model.
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Giveaway extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia, HasUuids;

    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'terms_and_conditions',
        'privacy_policy',
        'date_start',
        'date_end'
    ];

    
    protected $casts = [
        'date_start' => 'datetime',
        'date_end' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function participants(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Participant::class, 'participant_giveaway', 'giveaway_uuid', 'fiscal_code')
            ->withPivot('drawn', 'code', 'expiration_date', 'status', 'created_at')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function drawableParticipants(): Collection
    {
        return $this->participants()->where('drawn', 0)->get()->pluck('participant');
    }
}


This is my Participant model.
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Database\Factories\ParticipantFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Participant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'date_start',
        'date_end'
    ];

    public function giveaways(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->BelongsToMany(Giveaway::class, 'participant_giveaway', 'fiscal_code', 'giveaway_uuid')
            ->withPivot('drawn', 'code', 'expiration_date', 'status', 'created_at')->withTimestamps();
    }
}


Edit: I made a dump of the query being run when accessing the giveaway's participants through the relationship. I get: "select * from participants inner join participant_giveaway on participants.id = participant_giveaway.fiscal_code where participant_giveaway.giveaway_uuid = ?". The problem is that Laravel is joining the participants table on the id instead of the fiscal_code. I correctly set up the fields on which to join in the model so I do get why it does not join on them.

Just to be sure, could you have exactly 2 giveaway rows, with 2 participants, and have 1 giveaway relate to 1 participant, and the other giveaway to the other participant and get the data just to see what happens?

Tried it. It returns an empty collection for both cases. I also double checked the fields and their values in the db and they are correct.

Since I could not figure out why Laravel still persists to join on the id column instead of the fiscal_code, I opted for the easiest road and changed the participants primary key from id to fiscal_code.
Furthrmore, I also had a typo in my Participant giveaways() method. Instead of using this->belongsToMany() I was using this->BelongsToMany (with a capital B).
Edit: I opened an issue on their repo and told me I had to pass another argument on the the belongsToMany method (from either side) to customize the joining column on the participants table, like so:
public function participants(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Participant::class, 'participant_giveaway', 'giveaway_uuid', 'fiscal_code',
            relatedKey: 'fiscal_code')
        ->withPivot('drawn', 'created_at')
        ->withTimestamps();
}


It looks like the issue may stem from the way you're defining the relationships and the way you're retrieving the participants. Here are a couple of suggestions to resolve this:
Pivot Table Configuration: Ensure that your pivot table (participant_giveaway) uses the correct column names. Your current definition seems correct, but double-check that the actual database structure matches the specified fields.
Eager Loading: When you retrieve the giveaway, consider using eager loading to ensure you get the correct participants. Use the following when querying:
$giveaway = Giveaway::with('participants')->find($uuid);
Correct Usage of pluck: In your drawableParticipants method, you're trying to pluck participants but might be referencing them incorrectly. Change it to:
    public function drawableParticipants(): Collection
{
    return $this->participants()->where('drawn', 0)->get();
}

Check the UUID: Make sure that the UUID you're using to find the giveaway is correct and corresponds to the correct participants.

I tried what you suggested and unfortunately nothing worked. I recreated the scenario suggested by @matiaslauriti in the comment above and now I am getting empty collections returned even though the relantioship on the db side works perfectly.
